# Prestigio Multipad PMP5101C Quad 10" fails to install driver in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I just got a Prestigio Multipad PMP5101C Quad 10" tablet and attached it to the computer as I intend to use it for development.
The driver search shows error and I can't see the tablet as an USB device. 
Where can I download driver for it as their official support site offers firmware only?

Comment: What's the error you get? Have you tried it on a different computer?

Comment: The automatic driver installer shows a red x stating that it couldn't find any driver. If I use the Device Manager and choose Search for hardware changes, it starts the driver wizard  which finds no suitable driver.